# Powershell Script for SVN Export too slow

Tags: powershell, svn, visualsvn-server

I am using visualsvn in windows7 I am trying to export svn Repositories to a directory but the script works well but when i commit its taking 1 min  to upload a 1 kb files which is slow  can any help me if any code or changes to script I wrote a Powershell script here my code

post-commit.ps1

```
# Store hook arguments into variables with mnemonic names
$repos = $args[0]
$rev   = $args[1]

# Build path to svn.exe
$svn = "$env:VISUALSVN_SERVER\bin\svn.exe"

# Build url to repository
$urepos = $repos -replace "\\", "/"
$url = "file:///$urepos/"

# Export repository revision $rev to the D:\Xamp\htdocs\testfolder
&"$svn" export -r $rev --force --username user1 --password user1 "$url" D:\Xamp\htdocs\testfolder
```

i add calling in post-commit.bat in visualsvn

```
set repository=%1
set transaction=%2

PowerShell.exe D:\testrepositories\bas\hooks\post-commit %repository%
```

%transaction%

Comment: Is the commit slow even if you use CMD shell or other tools? Unexpected delays can be caused by many things. Maybe it's checking for revoked certificates? The server is way too busy? The network connection is problematic?

Comment: yes commit is slow i wrote in post hook in visualsvn i gave that  code in my question post-commit.bat

Comment: This is not a Powershell problem then. It could be an antivirus issue on client and/or server as well. Research troubleshooting steps for generic SVN slowness issues.